# checking every digit in a number for oddness

Tags: c

I was writing a function which checks if every digit in a number is odd. I came accross this weird behaviour. Why does the second function return different (incorrect) results, eventhough its basically the same? (implemented in an opposite way)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int all_odd_1(int n) {
 if (n == 0) return 0;
 if (n < 0) n = -n;

 while (n > 0) {
  if (n&1 == 1)
     n /= 10;
  else
     return 0;
  }

return 1;
}


int all_odd_2(int n) {
 if (n == 0) return 0;
 if (n < 0) n = -n;

 while (n > 0) {
  if (n&1 == 0)
     return 0;
  else
     n /= 10;
  }

return 1;
}


int main() {

 printf("all_odd_1\n");
 printf("%d\n", all_odd_1(-131));
 printf("%d\n", all_odd_1(121));
 printf("%d\n", all_odd_1(2242));
 printf("-----------------\n");
 printf("all_odd_2\n");
 printf("%d\n", all_odd_2(131));
 printf("%d\n", all_odd_2(121));
 printf("%d\n", all_odd_2(2242));
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `==` operator has higher precedence than the `&` operator, so your `if (n&1 == 0)` statement is not doing what you expect!

(and the `if (n&1 == 1)` statement works only by coincidence that `1 == 1` evaluates to 1 ;)

Answer (score 10):

```
warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of '&'
```

Well, how about adding them ? Change `n&1` to `(n&1)`. Always ask for warnings.

Comment: I did not get any warnings, nor I am able to set them. Which compiler are you using. What kind of options are you passing to it?

Comment: I can't say for sure which compiler nc3b is using, but `gcc -Wall` gives the verbatim warning. http://gcc.gnu.org/

Comment: Yes, I use gcc. I didn't just mention `use gcc -Wall` because the OP didn't mention his compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Operator precedence. `n & 1 == 0` is equivalent to `n & (1 == 0)`

Answer (score 2):

It is a problem related to the order of execution. Try to use if ((n&1) == 0) in all_odd_2 and everything will work.